# Logout if token is expired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, token

I'm working on a react application that consists of many API requests. The structure of the application is

When logging in, I'm receiving a token on response and I'm saving the token in my local storage to be used in other API requests.

This token is expired every 30 minutes and if I do an API request after 30 minutes, I'm receiving a status of 401 in my request. I'm using this 401 status to do my logging out and clearing token data in local storage.

**Example request**

```
export function stationDailyUsage(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(dailyUsageLoading());
        axios.get(`${API_URL}/Dashboard/DailyUsage?type=${data.type}&date=${data.date}`, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.success === true) {
                    dispatch(dailyUsageSuccess(res.data));
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                if(error.response.status === 401){
                    dispatch(logout());
                }
              });
    }
}
```

So to logout this way I have to do this check for every API I use (Around 40 APIs ). Is this the best approach to follow or is there a better way to handle the logout. I've read about `axios interceptors` but was not clear about how to implement it in my system. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think using the axios interceptor would be better, and in your case you should also get **refresh token** as well with the auth token. 
So whenever you make first API call after 30min and you find that it says 401 then you should use that refresh token to get the new token and update the token in local storage.

Comment: In my case , i don't have a refresh token

Answer (score 3):

Put this code in your project initialize or loading section, and run it once
then every time you call `axios` this code will check errors

Change your variable here and use it

```
  // Add a request interceptor
  axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    if (token) {
      config.headers.credentials = 'include';
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      config.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
      config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    }

    return config;
  }, (error) => {
    alert('interceptor request has error');
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

  // Add a response interceptor
  axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    return response;
  }, (error) => {

    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error &&
      (error.response.data.session === false || error.response.data.session === "false")) {
      localStorage.removeItem("userId"); // <-- add your var
      window.location = "/";   // <-- add your path
    }
    else if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error && error.response.data.error.message) {
      toastMessage(error.response.data.error.message, 1);
    }
    else
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem("userId"); // <-- add your var
        window.location = "/";  // <-- add your path
      } else
        return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own wrapper for the `axios` and it should be something like this:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const request = axios.create({
  baseURL: backUrl,
  timeout: 5000,
});

export const get = url => {
  const expiresIn = localStorage.getItem('expiresIn');
  const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');

  if (expiresIn && Date.now() > expiresIn) {
    const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
    request
      .post('/oauth/token', {
        grant_type: 'refresh_token',
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
      })
      .then(res => {
        store.dispatch(
          loginSubmitted(
            res.data.access_token,
            res.data.refresh_token,
            res.data.expires_in,
          ),
        );

        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', res.data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', res.data.refresh_token);
        localStorage.setItem('expiresIn', res.data.expires_in);

        return request.get(url, {
          headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${res.data.access_token}` },
          accessToken: res.data.access_token,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
        localStorage.removeItem('refreshToken');
        localStorage.removeItem('expiresIn');
      });
  }

  return request.get(url, {
    headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${accessToken}` },
    accessToken,
  });
};
```

so it will check the `exprire_date` before each request and send a new request for a new token so user won't log out

Answer (score -1):

Yes you're partially correct, in case you cannot use refresh tokens (which should be given to maintain the login state ideally).

Use axios interceptors to intercept the response before it becomes an error like 401 which needs to be handled.

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // 200 type responses, this should be left as it is
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Handle your 401 error, maybe the UI changes and removing from local storage
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```