# JWT Token Authorization in Asp.Net Core Web API

Tags: reactjs, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using React as my Single Page application and also generating the token using Microsoft AD Authentication OAuth using the below code.

[image]

I am using my SPA for authentication but for authorization and access controls I wanted to fine grain the access controls in my web api using attributes in controller actions like [Authorize(Roles="Admin")].

Can anyone help me here how to implement the authorization by calling the action methods from my React app by passing the Bearer token in headers of each request. I want to control my web api logic using the claims in the token by using roles.

your inputs are really appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: axios Bearer token setting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59484512/logout-if-token-is-expired/59484768#59484768

Comment: Hi Babak, Thanks for the reference link. But my problem is with the authorization part in asp.net core web api. How to handle the jwt token use claims in the token to control the logic in api

Comment: You could refer to the docs:https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/11/aspnet-core-3-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api