# Issue with laravel sanctum authenticating Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am using laravel(8) with sanctum(2.11) to power spa authentication (Reactjs) and using Axios to consume the API,
I followed the laravel docs but I got an issue with authenticated routes, which is I receive 401 unauthorized always, however in postman I get the appropriate response.
[image: This is the request]

and here is my .env:
[image: my .env file]

and here is my Axios client configurations:
[image]

Comment: I don't think the double quotation symbol is needed on the Authorization header, have you checked that?

Comment: @felixbmmm i use string interpolation in Javascript, Please reconsider i did updated the post with my axios configurations

Comment: Have you tried to simply add the token like such? 'Bearer ' + token? Also, just checked that the double quotation is not supposed to be there (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization)

Comment: Can you share the docs' link here? Can't seem to find it.

Comment: I think you are right, this was the issue, but should I send the token in the header or Axios should handle it for me with the withCredintials option set to true?

Comment: Depends on your preferences, here's another option I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712034/how-to-properly-set-axios-default-headers